# Wobbly Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, design

I bought a MacBook Pro yesterday, and it's "wobbly".  My front-right leg is about 1 mm or so shorter than my back-left leg.
Is there a quick fix for this (I was thinking of just making it bigger by myself) or should I send it back to Apple?

Comment: I found out I can solve the problem by sliding a piece of paper underneath it.  I think I have OCD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most times I have seen this, the table is the thing not level. Does closing the lid and rotating it ninety degrees with the apple logo staying over the same spot actually move the short peg or is the table the issue?

Comment: I tried that and it was the table.  Very strange, but I'm relieved :)

Comment: "If your Apple MacBook wobbles, straighten your table" http://designarchives.aiga.org/#/entries/%2Bid%3A15483/_/detail/relevance/asc/0/7/15483/if-your-harvey-probber-chair-wobbles-straighten-your-floor/1

Answer (score 2):

I suggest taking it back. I suspect that the bottom plate with the legs on it wasn't attached properly (it can flex a bit), but if it's a brand new device it's easier just to get it replaced than to try to fix it yourself.